# Selecting as expression from a single object

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can an expression be applied to a single item? Right now I have an expression that can be used on a list or any collection that supports the Select extension method. I would like to expand that functionality to single objects also. Here's an example to clarify what I mean:

```
private static readonly Expression<Func<Book, BookDto>> AsBookDto =
        x => new BookDto
        {
            Title = x.Title,
            Author = x.Author.Name,
            Genre = x.Genre,
            Description = x.Description,
            Price = x.Price,
            PublishDate = x.PublishDate
        };
```

With this expression I can do something like this:

```
IQueryable<BookDto> books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Author)
.Where(x => x.AuthorId == authorId).Select(AsBookDto);
```

What I'm looking for is a way to reuse that Expression so that when in a method I receive a Book with author included I could do something like this:

```
public BookDto SampleMethod(Book propertiesIncludedBook)
{
    //this does not compile because Book does not have a Select method.
    return propertiesIncludedBook.Select(AsBookDto);
}
```

Comment: Does that mean that you actually retrieved a full `Book` object from the database? Usually, the way DTO classes are used is by directly projecting to them, like you did in your first example. Doing what you ask is possible, but probably not what you want, since it will not behave the same way: for example, `x.Author.Name` will then suddenly cause a `NullReferenceException` if `x.Author == null` (which may happen even if the author is set in the database). Can you explain when and how you want to use your `SampleMethod`?

Comment: Yup, the reason I'm trying to do this is because I get a single item back from the database using FirstOrDefault (including all the objects that will be used in the expression), and then depending on the state of the retrieved object I will choose which expression to apply on it to transfer it into a Dto. Suppose a retrieved object has Inviter and Invitee properties(pocos), now depending on the state I will either use AsInviterToDto or AsInviteeToDto.

Comment: Another approach could be to use AutoMapper. At this point in your code you could choose which mapping to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of LINQ extensions work on `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`, in your case what you need is just a *normal* function/delegate but if you want to keep same syntax you use with LINQ just write your own extension method for that:

```
public static TOutput SelectSingle<TInput, TOutput>(
    this TInput obj,
    Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> expression)
{
    return expression.Compile()(obj);
}
```

Used as:

```
public BookDto SampleMethod(Book propertiesIncludedBook)
{
    return propertiesIncludedBook.SelectSingle(AsBookDto);
}
```

Error checking is omitted but as you can see there is not such benefit to use it directly like this:

```
public BookDto SampleMethod(Book propertiesIncludedBook)
{
    return AsBookDto.Compile()(propertiesIncludedBook);
}
```

**Edit** alternative splitting expression definition with a separate `Func<Book, BookDto>` works but makes expression itself pretty useless. Removed.

Comment: Your alternative would never work, the expression tree would no longer contain any useful information, it would simply hold "invoke variable `AsBookDtoFunc`", with no information on what `AsBookDtoFunc` does. But your first suggestion doesn't look like it can be improved further.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I get an error on the first example you provided. It says to me that expression.Compile() has 2 constructors, one that is the default empty constructor and another one that accepts a System.RunTime.CompilerServices.DebugInfoGenerator object, none of which are valid for 'TInput obj'

Comment: I was able to get the first example working by changing the expression.Compile() part to ´Func<TInput, TOutput> fun = expression.Compile();
            return fun(obj);´

Comment: @neo112 I think Adriano meant `expression.Compile()(obj)`. What you figured out would work exactly the same way, though.

Comment: @hvd pretty right, in that way expression itself is meaningless.

Comment: @neo112 yes, typo. Correct is how it's done is second example (or the way you did it).