# Nest two lambda style Func Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

Is there an easy way to combine two lambda style Expressions like the following (I know that the sample expressions could be combined to one manually, but what if the innerExpression is returned by some function and not known in advance). They have the same input paramter type so in theory the ParameterExpression could be used for both of them.

```
Expression<Func<Source, Subtype>> innerExpression = x => new Subtype {
    Subfield1 = x.SomeField;
    Subfield2 = x.SomeOtherField;
}

Expression<Func<Source, Target>> finalExpression = x => new Target {
    Field1 = x.Other1,
    Field2 = x.Other2,
    Field3 = x.Items.Where(y => y.Field == true).SingleOrDefault(),
    Field4 = innerExpression(x) // <= Does not work that way
}
```

Comment: Expressions must be compiled before you invoke them (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434498/selecting-as-expression-from-a-single-object/22434706#22434706) for an example). Field4 is SubType, not Expression<...> then you can't simply assign an expression to it. That said this may prevent consumer of finalExpression to work as expected (for example if you're using LINQ To SQL or Entities).

Comment: The expression will never be compiled I need the expression tree for further operations, it would just be a lot more work and less readable to create the Expression tree by hand. But as I expected there is no easy way to combine them.

Comment: @Fionn There *is* actually a (relatively) easy way to combine them.  You can write the expression manipulation code *once* in a sufficiently generalized manor, allowing you to then perform the specific operation you are trying to do here without needing to do any permission manipulation.

Comment: You can use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So what we'll do here is create a method that takes an expression that takes one parameter and computes another, then another expression that accepts the same parameter as the first, the output type of the first function, and then computes an entirely new value.

The idea here is that this expression will represent the invocation of the first function, and then the second function takes the same input value, its output, and computes a new value.  In reality though, rather than invoking the expression internally, it will inline the expression wherever the parameter representing its output is used.

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Combine<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], param)
        .Replace(second.Parameters[1], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

This is dependant on the following method for replacing all instance of one expression with another:

```
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
```

The idea is really quite simple.  Just replace all instances of the parameter representing the output with the body of the other method, while also ensuring the parameter expressions are consistent between the two.

Now we can write this:

```
Expression<Func<Source, Subtype>> innerExpression = x => new Subtype
{
    Subfield1 = x.SomeField,
    Subfield2 = x.SomeOtherField,
};

Expression<Func<Source, Target>> finalExpression = innerExpression.Combine(
    (x, sub) => new Target
{
    Field1 = x.Other1,
    Field2 = x.Other2,
    Field3 = x.Items.Where(y => y.Field == true).SingleOrDefault(),
    Field4 = sub
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out by @svick in a comment, the correct way of doing this is to use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), which is  a library the supports common manipulations for building expression trees.

In your case you would have the following:

```
Expression<Func<Source, Subtype>> innerExpression = x => new Subtype {
    Subfield1 = x.SomeField;
    Subfield2 = x.SomeOtherField;
}

Expression<Func<Source, Target>> secondExpression = x => new Target {
    Field1 = x.Other1,
    Field2 = x.Other2,
    Field3 = x.Items.Where(y => y.Field == true).SingleOrDefault(),
    Field4 = innerExpression.Invoke(x)
}

Expression<Func<Source, Target>> finalExpression = secondExpression.Expand();
```