# Can I reuse code for selecting a custom DTO object for a child property with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

When querying using Entity Framework Core, I am using expressions to convert to DTO objects, which works well for the object, and any child collections.

A simplified example:

Model:

```
public class Model
{
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChildModel> ChildModels { get; set; }

    // Other properties, collections, etc.

    public static Expression<Func<Model, ModelDto>> AsDto =>
        model => new ModelDto
        { 
            ModelId = model.ModelId,
            ModelName = model.ModelName,
            ChildModels = model.ChildModels.AsQueryable().Select(ChildModel.AsDto).ToList()
        };
}
```

Query:

```
dbContext.Models.Where(m => SomeCriteria).Select(Model.AsDto).ToList();
```

My question is about trying to find a way to do something similar for a child that is not a collection. If I have added to my model:

```
public AnotherChildModel AnotherChildModel { get; set; }
```

I can add a conversion in the expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<Model, ModelDto>> AsDto =>
    model => new ModelDto
    { 
        ModelId = model.ModelId,
        ModelName = model.ModelName,
        ChildModels = model.ChildModels.AsQueryable().Select(ChildModel.AsDto).ToList(),
        AnotherChildModel = new AnotherChildModelDto
        {
            AnotherChildModelId = model.AnotherChildModelId
        }
    };
```

But, I have not found a good way to avoid repeating this code every time that I need to convert the second child model to a DTO object. The expressions work for the main object and any child collections, but not for single entities. Is there a way to add the equivalent of a .Select() for a single entity?

Comment: Have you looked at Automapper?

Comment: I found a similar situation, maybe this can help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434498/selecting-as-expression-from-a-single-object

Comment: @Dai - I have looked at Automapper some, but I am not familiar with it, and have struggled to get started with it, especially as part of the Entity Framework queries. It does seem like it might be able to do what I am looking for though.

Comment: @hijinxbassist - That answer is helpful! I thought I had tried something similar in the past and had issues (with the compiled expressions resulting many separate queries per row of results), but in testing similar code to that answer now, it seems to be working. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several libraries which allows to do that in intuitive way:

[LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)

```cs
[Expandable(nameof(AsDtoImpl))]
public static ModelDto AsDto(Model model)
{
   _asDtoImpl ??= AsDtoImpl() .Compile();
   return _asDtoImpl(model);
}

private static Func<Model, ModelDto> _asDtoImpl;

private static Expression<Func<Model, ModelDto>> AsDtoImpl =>
    model => new ModelDto
    { 
        ModelId = model.ModelId,
        ModelName = model.ModelName,
        ChildModels = model.ChildModels.AsQueryable().Select(ChildModel.AsDto).ToList(),
        AnotherChildModel = new AnotherChildModelDto
        {
            AnotherChildModelId = model.AnotherChildModelId
        }
    };
```

```
dbContext.Models
   .Where(m => SomeCriteria).Select(m => Model.AsDto(m))
   .AsExpandable()
   .ToList();
```

**UPDATE**: For EF Core, LINQKit can be confugred globally and `AsExpanding()` can be omitted.

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

[NeinLinq](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq) - almost the same as in LINQKit

```cs
[InjectLambda]
public static ModelDto AsDto(Model model)
{
   _asDto ??= AsDto() .Compile();
   return _asDto(model);
}

private static Func<Model, ModelDto> _asDto;

private static Expression<Func<Model, ModelDto>> AsDto =>
    model => new ModelDto
    { 
        ModelId = model.ModelId,
        ModelName = model.ModelName,
        ChildModels = model.ChildModels.AsQueryable().Select(ChildModel.AsDto).ToList(),
        AnotherChildModel = new AnotherChildModelDto
        {
            AnotherChildModelId = model.AnotherChildModelId
        }
    };
```

```
dbContext.Models
   .Where(m => SomeCriteria).Select(m => Model.AsDto(m))
   .ToInjectable()
   .ToList();
```

**UPDATE**: For EF Core, NenLinq can be confugred globally and `ToInjectable()` can be omitted.

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithLambdaInjection(); // enabling NeinLinq extension
```

[DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler) - less verbose than others

```cs
[Computed]
public static ModelDto AsDto(Model model)
  => new ModelDto
    { 
        ModelId = model.ModelId,
        ModelName = model.ModelName,
        ChildModels = model.ChildModels.AsQueryable().Select(ChildModel.AsDto).ToList(),
        AnotherChildModel = new AnotherChildModelDto
        {
            AnotherChildModelId = model.AnotherChildModelId
        }
    }
```

```
dbContext.Models
   .Where(m => SomeCriteria).Select(m => Model.AsDto(m))
   .Decompile()
   .ToList();
```

All libraries do the same thing - correct expression tree before EF Core processing. All of them need additional call to inject it's own `IQueryProvider`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

With the additional call needed that you mentioned at the end, this would be the "AsExpandable()" call in LINQKit for example? So then this would be needed on any queries using these?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But this call can be done in the root of the query, or in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any third party library. The key is to use `AsQueryable()` before the `Select` is made. You can of course get it to work without it but there is a high probability that you will fetch more columns than you actually need.

For your code it would be something like:

```
dbContext.Models.Where(m => SomeCriteria).AsQueryable().Select(Model.AsDto).ToList();
```

Example:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

using var context = new MyDbContext();
context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
context.Database.EnsureCreated();

var blogPostIds = context.Blogs
    .Select(b => new
    {
        BlogId = b.Id,
        PostIds = b.Posts.AsQueryable().Select(Helper.Selector).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();

public static class Helper
{
    public static Expression<Func<Post, int>> Selector
        => x => x.Id;
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Selector;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
}

public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76047514/3850405

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without use of any third party toolkit by subclassing [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/expression-trees-translating#create-a-modified-copy) and using it to edit the expression tree for your outer `AsDto()` method and inject the inner `AsDto()` method of `AnotherChildModel`.  The basic idea here is to initially define a [curried](https://stackoverflow.com/q/411572) version of your `AsDto()` expression that takes a `Func<AnotherChildModel, AnotherChildModelDto>` as an additional argument, then use `ExpressionVisitor` to create a modified copy that substitutes the curried functional argument with the expression for  `AnotherChildModel.AsDto`.  Since this method works directly with expression trees, it is independent of the specific LINQ framework you are using.

To see how this can be done, first define the following extension methods that inject and/or compose some `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>` into some containing expression tree:

```cs
public static partial class ExpressionExtensions
{
    // Uncurry and compose an Expression<Func<T1, Func<T2, T3>, TResult>> into an Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> by composing with an Expression<Func<T2, T3>>
    public static Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> Inject<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T1, Func<T2, T3>, TResult>> outer, Expression<Func<T2, T3>> inner) =>
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, TResult>>(
            new InvokeReplacer((outer.Parameters[1], inner)).Visit(outer.Body), 
            false, outer.Parameters[0]);

    // Compose two Func<Tx, Ty> expressions with compatible generic parameters into a third.
    public static Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> Compose<T1, T2, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T2, TResult>> outer, Expression<Func<T1, T2>> inner) =>
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, TResult>>(
            new ParameterReplacer(new [] {(outer.Parameters[0], inner.Body)}).Visit(outer.Body), 
            false, inner.Parameters[0]);    
}

class InvokeReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    // Replace an Invoke() with the body of a lambda, replacing the formal paramaters of the lambda with the arguments of the invoke.
    // TODO: Handle replacing of functions that are not invoked but just passed as parameters to some external method, e.g.
    //   collection.Select(map) instead of collection.Select(i => map(i))
    readonly Dictionary<Expression, LambdaExpression> funcsToReplace;
    public InvokeReplacer(params (Expression func, LambdaExpression replacement) [] funcsToReplace) =>
        this.funcsToReplace = funcsToReplace.ToDictionary(p => p.func, p => p.replacement);
    protected override Expression VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression invoke) => 
        funcsToReplace.TryGetValue(invoke.Expression, out var lambda)
        ? (invoke.Arguments.Count != lambda.Parameters.Count
            ? throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrong number of arguments")
            : new ParameterReplacer(lambda.Parameters.Zip(invoke.Arguments)).Visit(lambda.Body))
        : base.VisitInvocation(invoke);
}   

class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    // Replace formal parameters (e.g. of a lambda body) with some containing expression in scope.
    readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> parametersToReplace;
    public ParameterReplacer(IEnumerable<(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression replacement)> parametersToReplace) =>
        this.parametersToReplace = parametersToReplace.ToDictionary(p => p.parameter, p => p.replacement);
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p) => 
        parametersToReplace.TryGetValue(p, out var e) ? e : base.VisitParameter(p);
}
```

Now you can write `Model.AsDto()` as follows:

```
// Lazily create the expression once and cache its value for performance.
static Lazy<Expression<Func<Model, ModelDto>>> AsDtoExpression = new(static () => {
    // Create a curried lambda with a Func<AnotherChildModel, AnotherChildModelDto> passed in:
    Expression<Func<Model, Func<AnotherChildModel, AnotherChildModelDto>, ModelDto>> asDtoCurried = 
        (model, map) => new ModelDto
        {
            // Set the values we can set directly:
            ModelId = model.ModelId,
            ModelName = model.ModelName,
            ChildModels = model.ChildModels.AsQueryable().Select(ChildModel.AsDto).ToList(),
            // But we can't call AnotherChildModel.AsDto() directly so sub in map for now.
            AnotherChildModelDto = map(model.AnotherChildModel), 
        };
    // Then inject AnotherChildModel.AsDto in place of the curried function:
    return asDtoCurried.Inject(AnotherChildModel.AsDto);
}); 

public static Expression<Func<Model, ModelDto>> AsDto => AsDtoExpression.Value;
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ChX1x4).

Notes:

- It might be tempting to simply invoke `AnotherChildModel.AsDto()` from within `Model.Dto()`.  While this may work for LINQ to Objects, it will not work with Entity Framework or other LINQ to Entities applications for reasons explained in *["The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities" - stumped!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284912/3744182)*.
- I lazily construct the expression tree and cache the result purely for performance reasons.
- The same idea could be used to inject `ChildModel.AsDto()`, eliminating the need for the `.AsQueryable()`:

  ```
  // Lazily create the expression once and cache its value for performance.
  static Lazy<Expression<Func<Model, ModelDto>>> AsDtoExpression = new(static () => {
      // Create a curried lambda with a Func<AnotherChildModel, AnotherChildModelDto> passed in:
      Expression<Func<Model, Func<ChildModel, ChildModelDto>, Func<AnotherChildModel, AnotherChildModelDto>, ModelDto>> asDtoCurried = 
          (model, map1, map2) => new ModelDto
          {
              // Set the values we can set directly:
              ModelId = model.ModelId,
              ModelName = model.ModelName,
              // And sum in maps for the child models' AsDto() methods for now.
              ChildModels = model.ChildModels.Select(c => map1(c)).ToList(),
              AnotherChildModelDto = map2(model.AnotherChildModel), 
          };
      // Now inject the child AsDto() methods in place of the curried functions.
      return asDtoCurried.Inject(ChildModel.AsDto, AnotherChildModel.AsDto);
  }); 

  public static partial class ExpressionExtensions
  {
      public static Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> Inject<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>(
          this Expression<Func<T1, Func<T2, T3>, Func<T4, T5>, TResult>> outer, 
          Expression<Func<T2, T3>> inner1, Expression<Func<T4, T5>> inner2) =>
          Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, TResult>>(
              new InvokeReplacer((outer.Parameters[1], inner1), (outer.Parameters[2], inner2)).Visit(outer.Body), 
              false, 
              outer.Parameters[0]);
  }
  ```

  Do note that, while replacing `Select(c => map1(c))` is implemented, replacing `Select(map1)` is not.

  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/opLuAH).
- For further reading on editing of expression trees see *[Translate expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/expression-trees-translating#create-a-modified-copy)* and *[Why would I want to use an ExpressionVisitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41432852/3744182)*.