# How to avoid a NullReferenceException when using a nested property via projection with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm having an issue performing a DTO projection with Entity Framework Core 2.2 whereby one class has a property that references another property from a parent class. When I attempt the projection a `NullReferenceException` is thrown because the parent object is `null`.

Here is a contrived example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public class Vendor
{
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice => ItemPrice * (1 + Vendor.Tax);
}

public class ItemDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}

private Task<IEnumerable<ItemDto>> Projection()
{
    var results = await _context.Item
        .Select(t => new ItemDto()
        {
            Name = t.Name,
            TotalPrice = t.TotalPrice
        })
        .ToListAsync();

    return results;
}
```

I am able to get this to work by either:

- Grabbing the results of the query first and then performing the projection, but this ends up pulling unnecessary data from the database
- Specifying `TotalPrice = t.ItemPrice * (1 + t.Vendor.Tax)` within the projection, but this is redefining the logic, so isn't ideal

I've also tried including `Vendor` in the query, but that doesn't help either. Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Vendor!=null ? ItemPrice * (1 + Vendor.Tax) : ItemPrice;`

Comment: @Neil that is a workaround, but there will never be a scenario whereby an Item does not have a corresponding Vendor so we would want it to fail if that was the case. In the example I've given, if I pull the data first, the Item does have an associated Vendor, but during the projection it's not able to access it because I guess it hasn't been populated yet as it's still just a query.

Comment: Actually, `Item` shouldn't have any logic in it IMO, it should just be used for persistance.

Comment: @Neil - I think you could be right about that and I believe the goal will eventually be to remove it, but it's just something I'm having to work around currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Translator cannot look into property body, so it cannot create appropriate query.

Simpler solution is to do that in the query

```cs
private Task<IEnumerable<ItemDto>> Projection()
{
    var results = await _context.Item
        .Select(t => new ItemDto()
        {
            Name = t.Name,
            TotalPrice = t.ItemPrice * (1 + t.Vendor.Tax)
        })
        .ToListAsync();

    return results;
}
```

For sure it is not reusable way. So maybe you will find this my answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316

Comment: I thought that would be the case. I'll take a look at your other answer, as it would be nice if I could avoid redefining the logic in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your projection is not actually loading all the data it requires:

```
private Task<IEnumerable<ItemDto>> Projection()
{
  var results = await _context.Item
    .Include(x=>x.Vendor) <--- Make sure you have all the data required
    .Select(t => new ItemDto()
    {
        Name = t.Name,
        TotalPrice = t.TotalPrice
    })
    .ToListAsync();

  return results;
}
```

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried, but doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Because it still throws a `NullReference` exception... You don't typically need the `Include` statements when projecting anyway.

Comment: @Neil, with custom projection EF ignores your `Include`. Remember that.