# how to properly refactor conditions inside LinQ queries with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have some complex LinQ queries having sets of similar complex expressions:

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> MyRepoMt1()
{
  return  _myContext.MyEntities.Where(<several rules A>> && different stuff) .ToList() ;
}

IEnumerable<MyEntity> MyRepoMt2()
{
  return  _myContext.MyEntities.Where(<several rules A>> && different stuff) .ToList(); // Same rules A than previous method
}
…
IEnumerable<MyEntity> MyRepoMt3()
{
  return  _myContext.MyEntities.Where(<several rules B> > && different stuff) .ToList();
}

IEnumerable<MyEntity> MyRepoMt4()
{
  return  _myContext.MyEntities.Where(<several rules B> && different stuff) .ToList(); // Same rules B than previous method
}

IEnumerable<MyEntity> MyRepoMt5()
{
  return  _myContext.MyEntities.Where(<several rules A> || <several rules B>) .ToList(); // Same rules A and B than previous method
}
```

…

I would like to refactor  and  in the best possible way.
My first attempt was as follows, using a method returning a bool:

```
Bool CheckRulesA(MyEntity e){ …}
Bool CheckRulesB(MyEntity e){ …}
```

I called it this way:

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> MyRepoMt1()
{
  return  _myContext.MyEntities.Where(e => CheckRulesA( e) && different stuff) .ToList() ;
}
```

It failed because EF could not execute CheckRulesA on server side and threw an exception.

I changed it to a method dealing with IQueryable :

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> CheckRulesA(IQueryable<MyEntity> query)
{
 Return query .Where(e => …..).ToList() ;
}
```

This solved my previous issue.
I can do :

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> MyRepoMt1()
{
  return  CheckRulesA(_myContext.MyEntities).Where(different stuff…).ToList() ;
}
```

I could enhance it with an extension method but it s not my point right now.

But it is not fully acceptable as it does not handle cases with || operators (My last MyRepoMt5() example).

In this last  scenario, I need to return entities that check RulesA OR RulesB.
I don’t want to do something as ugly as

```
Var q2 = (CheckRulesA(_myContext.MyEntities) || CheckRulesB(_myContext.MyEntities)).Distinct();
```

This looks terribly awful to me.

How am I to handle this properly ?

Comment: Take a look at Predicate Builder http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66952509/10646316) You can do the same with predicates.