# How to avoid repeating ToLists when using LINQ and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `DbSet<T>` that I need to project onto a different type. For the projection, I use `Select`.

If I call directly `Select` on my `DbSet<T>` like:

```
private IEnumerable<PersonPOCO> _getPersons(ILocator loc)
{
    using(var service = loc.GetService())
    {
        return service.GetPersons().Select(p => Mapper.ToPoco(p));
    }
}
```

This will throw a `NotSupportedException` because `Select` is not recognized by entity framework (which is kinda obvious).

So I'll need to "concretize" the list by calling `ToList()` :

```
private IEnumerable<PersonPOCO> _getPersons(ILocator loc)
{
    using(var service = loc.GetService())
    {
        return service.GetPersons()
                      .ToList()
                      .Select(p => Mapper.ToPoco(p));
    }
}
```

If I leave it like this, `Select` being 'lazy' will only be evaluated when the list is really enumerated. But by that time, the Context used by the service will have been disposed (outside of the `using` statement) so I will have a `DbContextDisposedException`.

So I need to directly enumerate the list inside the `using`

```
private IEnumerable<PersonPOCO> _getPersons(ILocator loc)
{
    using(var prov = loc.GetService())
    {
        return prov.GetPersons()
            .ToList()
            .Select(p => Mapper.ToPOCO(p))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Is there no way I can avoid calling `ToList()` twice in the same instruction?

Comment: EF does 'recognise' `Select`, it's the `Mapper.ToPoco` that it doesn't know how to process. What is that?

Comment: The second `ToList` is unnecessary, because the first will enumerate the collection immediately. Only the `Select` is lazily evaluated, which will be operating on an in-memory list at that point.

Comment: Technically what you need (in case you can't rewrite `Select` to be translatable by replacing mapper call with mapping expression) before `Select` is `AsEnumerable()`, not `ToList()` .

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay well, *yes*, but if you're going to buffer the data locally, you might as well do it *after* the projections, so that if it is consumed multiple times the projection isn't repeated

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, you're right about that. The comment was more because OP thought that omitting the second `ToList` would cause an exception.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make `Mapper.ToPoco` "recognized" by EF ? For the record, this is only a static method that returns a `new ParamTypePOCO` with nothing fancy, only primitives.

Comment: You could change the `ToPoco` method to return an `Expression` or use AutoMapper which has some [EF features](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html)

Comment: @ArthurAttout, maybe this my answer will be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316

Comment: +1 on Automapper.. `ProjectTo` will work the SQL down to just what is needed to populate your DTO. (No need to reinvent the wheel)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that EF doesn't know what to do with `DataViewMapper.ToPOCO`. You can use `AsEnumerable()` to switch to LINQ-to-Objects:

```cs
using (var prov = arg.GetProvider())
{
    return prov.GetParamTypes()
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(p => DataViewMapper.ToPOCO(p))
        .ToList();
}
```

This avoids an intermediate list/array/etc allocation.

Comment: The thing is I see `AsEnumerable` just as boilerplate as `ToList`, so it doesn't save me from an additional instruction to make my query. I'll go with you suggestion to change `DataViewMapper.ToPOCO` return an `Expression`, which would actually save me an instruction.