# Is it possible to compose System.Linq.Expressions.Expression from smaller expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have a simple expression that I use to convert domain objects into DTOs.

```
public static Expression<Func<Person, PersonDetailsShallow>> ToPersonDetailsShallow
    => (person) => new PersonDetailsShallow()
    {
        PersonId = person.Id,
        Tag = person.Tag
    };

public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; internal set; }
    public string Tag { get; internal set; }
}

public class PersonDetailsShallow
{
    public string PersonId { get; internal set; }
    public string Tag { get; internal set; }
}
```

I am now dreaming of a way to embed this `Expression` into another expression, something like

```
// define one more entity and dto to have something to work with
public class Purchase
{
    public double Price { get; internal set; }
    public Person Purchaser { get; internal set; }
}

public class PurchaseDetailsShallow
{
    public double Price { get; internal set; }
    public PersonDetailsShallow Purchaser { get; internal set; }
}

public static Expression<Func<Purchase, PurchaseDetailsShallow>> ToPurchaseDetailsShallow
    => (purchase) => new PurchaseDetailsShallow()
    {
        Price = purchase.Price,
        Purchaser = ExpandExpression(ToPersonDetailsShallow, purchase.Purchaser)
    }
```

where `ExpandExpression` works some magic such that the resulting `ToPurchaseDetailsShallow` looks like this

```
(purchase) => new PurchaseDetailsShallow()
    {
        Price = purchase.Price,

        Purchaser = new PersonDetailsShallow()
        {
            PersonId = purchase.Purchaser.Id,
            Tag = purchase.Purchaser.Tag
        }
    }
```

It appears that there are libraries that can achieve this as shown in this question

[Can I reuse code for selecting a custom DTO object for a child property with EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66378438/can-i-reuse-code-for-selecting-a-custom-dto-object-for-a-child-property-with-ef)

but I am hoping for a simpler way that does not involve adding new dependencies.

---

I am aware that I could fake it using `Compile()` a la

```
public static Expression<Func<Purchase, PurchaseDetailsShallow>> ToPurchaseDetailsShallow
    => (purchase) => new PurchaseDetailsShallow()
    {
        Price = purchase.Price,
        Purchaser = ToPersonDetailsShallow.Compile()(purchase.Purchaser)
    }
```

which however does not create the right expression tree, but only shows similar behavior when evaluating the expression.

Comment: Generally speaking, expression lambdas are not particularly composable (there are simple cases you can do that a bit) without rolling up your sleaves and using the `Expression` factory methods to construct your tree by hand.  Learning how to do that is a bit of work, but once you get used to it, it's not unrealistic for you to be able to pull off any bit of composability you want.

Comment: Use `LINQKit` as I mentioned. If you do not have knowledge how to work with Expression Tree - it is wasting of time. Actually it is my implementation of `ExpandableAttribute` in `LINQKit`. If you do not want additional dependencies - just copy/paste code from `LINQKit`. Root is [ExpressionExpander.cs](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/src/LinqKit.Core/ExpressionExpander.cs)

Comment: Note that `ToPurchaseDetailsShallow` is an `Expression<>` so when you embed `ExpandExpression` in it the compiler won't create executable code to run it - you have to do that outside the `Expression<>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement a lambda expander for an `Expression` tree (there are other types of expanders that can be done), you need to mark the lambdas to expand by calling them using the `XInvoke` method, create an `ExpressionVisitor` to find the calls and expand them, and use the common `Expression` replace visitor to apply the arguments of `XInvoke` to the lambda you are expanding.

```
public static class ExpandXInvokeExt {
    public static TRes XInvoke<TArg1, TRes>(this Expression<Func<TArg1, TRes>> fnE, TArg1 arg1)
        => throw new InvalidOperationException($"Illegal call to XInvoke({fnE},{arg1})");

    public static TRes XInvoke<TArg1, TArg2, TRes>(this Expression<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TRes>> fnE, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2)
        => throw new InvalidOperationException($"Illegal call to XInvoke({fnE},{arg1},{arg2})");

    public static T ExpandXInvoke<T>(this T orig) where T : Expression => (T)new ExpandXInvokeVisitor().Visit(orig);

    public static T Evaluate<T>(this T e) where T : Expression => (T)((e is ConstantExpression c) ? c.Value : Expression.Lambda(e).Compile().DynamicInvoke());

    /// <summary>
    /// ExpressionVisitor to expand a MethodCallExpression of XInvoke with an applied version of the first argument,
    /// an Expression.
    /// </summary>
    public class ExpandXInvokeVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
        public override Expression Visit(Expression node) {
            if (node?.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call) {
                var callnode = (MethodCallExpression)node;
                if (callnode.Method.Name == "XInvoke" && callnode.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(ExpandXInvokeExt)) {
                    var lambda = (LambdaExpression)(callnode.Arguments[0].Evaluate());
                    Expression expr = lambda.Body;
                    for (int argNum = 1; argNum < callnode.Arguments.Count; ++argNum)
                        expr = expr.Replace(lambda.Parameters[argNum - 1], callnode.Arguments[argNum]);

                    return expr;
                }
            }

            return base.Visit(node);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces an Expression (reference Equals) with another Expression
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orig">The original Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="from">The from Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="to">The to Expression.</param>
    /// <returns>Expression with all occurrences of from replaced with to</returns>
    public static T Replace<T>(this T orig, Expression from, Expression to) where T : Expression => (T)new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(orig);

    /// <summary>
    /// ExpressionVisitor to replace an Expression (that is Equals) with another Expression.
    /// </summary>
    public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
        readonly Expression from;
        readonly Expression to;

        public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

This code provides `XInvoke` for one and two arguments, others can be added in the same way.

With these extensions available, you can write your `ToPurchaseDetailsShallow` like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Purchase, PurchaseDetailsShallow>> ToPurchaseDetailsShallowTemplate
    => (purchase) => new PurchaseDetailsShallow() {
        Price = purchase.Price,
        Purchaser = ToPersonDetailsShallow.Invoke(purchase.Purchaser)
    };

public static Expression<Func<Purchase, PurchaseDetailsShallow>> ToPurchaseDetailsShallow => ToPurchaseDetailsShallowTemplate.ExpandXInvoke();
```

Note: I used the name `XInvoke` so the compiler wouldn't confuse incorrect number of arguments with attempts to call `Expression.Invoke` (I don't think it should, but it does).

Note: With enough parentheses and casting, you can avoid the template variable, but I am not sure it makes anything better:

```
public static Expression<Func<Purchase, PurchaseDetailsShallow>> ToPurchaseDetailsShallow
    => ((Expression<Func<Purchase, PurchaseDetailsShallow>>)(
        (purchase) => new PurchaseDetailsShallow() {
            Price = purchase.Price,
            Purchaser = ToPersonDetailsShallow.XInvoke(purchase.Purchaser)
        })
       )
       .ExpandXInvoke();
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity what are the other types of Expanders you had in mind?

Comment: @Benj Here are a couple: 1 uses attributes to replace a method call with another `Expression` by calling another method e.g. replaces `f.RemoveAll("x..z")` with `f.Replace("x", "")...Replace("z", "")` by calling a `RemoveAllExpander` method during the visit 2. One that takes an `Expression` that contains `expressionvariable.Embed<T>()` and replaces the method call to `Embed` with the value of the `expressionvariable` e.g. `var inner2 = () => 4*8; Expression<Func<int,bool>> wrap2 = x => x == innter2.Body.Embed<int>(); var exp = wrap2.ExpandEmbed();` yields `exp` with value `x => x == 32`.