# LINQKit Leftjoin/GroupJoin : The query cannot be translated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linqkit

I'm using LINQKit in a query with LeftJoin in it :

```
return _context.User
            .LeftJoin(
                _context.JournalAcces,
                u => u.Login,
                j => j.LoginUtilisateur,
                (u, j) => new { U = u, J = j })
            .AsExpandable()
            .Select(x => new User
            {
                Login = x.U.Login,
                Date = x.J.Date,
                IsUsed = IsUsed().Invoke(x.U),
            })
            .ToList();
```

I get this error message : `the LINQ expression could not be translated`
But if I replace `LeftJoin` by `Join`, it works.

I also tried adding LINQKit configuration on DbContextOptions level :

```
builder
    .UseNpgsql(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding();
```

and deleted the .AsExpandable() from the query, but I got the same error :

```
return _context.User
                .LeftJoin(
                    _context.JournalAcces,
                    u => u.Login,
                    j => j.LoginUtilisateur,
                    (u, j) => new { U = u, J = j })
                .Select(x => new User
                {
                    Login = x.U.Login,
                    Date = x.J.Date,
                    IsUsed = IsUsed().Invoke(x.U),
                })
                .ToList();
```

Is this a bug in LINQKit or a limitation ? because I couldn't find any reference for it in the documentation nor in the open issues.

For reference, IsUsed is defined like this :

```
public static Expression<Func<User, bool>> IsUsed()
    {
        return x => x.Employement == "Employed";
    }
```

Comment: Show query which do not work, good query will not help in reproducing.

Comment: The query that does not work is that one with only replacing Join by LeftJoin

Comment: Standard LINQ has no operator `LeftJoin`. Probably something wrong with this function.

Comment: Yes, it is a LINQKit extension method. GroupJoin is standard Linq, and it show me the same error

Comment: Can you try to configure LINQKit via [WithExpressionExpanding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72099548/10646316) and remove `AsExpandable()`. Also correct your answer and post NON working query.

Comment: I updated my answer and included your comments