# How to apply Expression<Func> value selector in query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, linq-expressions

I have such code:

```
private static IQueryable<Word> filterAndOrderWords(IQueryable<Word> words, string phrase)
{
  return words
    .Where(it => it.Phrase.ToLower().Contains(phrase))
               ...
```

which now I would like to make more generic and remove hard coded using `Phrase` property. So I could change it to:

```
private static IQueryable<T> filterAndOrderText<T>(IQueryable<T> textRecords,
  Expression< Func<T,string>> selector, string phrase)
{
  return textRecords
    .Where(it => selector(it).ToLower().Contains(phrase))
    ...
```

But this does not compile. `selector.Compile()(it)` throws an exception (I used EF SQlite as source, and the message is I should rewrite the query).

So how to rewrite it so EF could understand the more generic version as well as the original one?

Comment: Are you ready to use `LINQKit` for such task or you need pure implementation?

Comment: With `LINQKit` it is simple ` .Where(it => selector.Invoke(it).ToLower().Contains(phrase))`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Pure implementation. I mean I can use library, but I would like to learn how to do it.

Comment: [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72099548/10646316) how to activate LINQKit and use `Invoke`