# How to use In-Memory Cache with eager loading in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, include, eager-loading, memorycache, in-memory-cache

I use In-Mmemory Cache to store some of the db models and I'm trying to use them in my queries using .Include(). The idea is not to change all my queries where I have cached models but instead somehow to update the Include() method so that EF Core will read that data from cache.

I tried this example but I'm getting some error:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, IEnumerable<MySecondEntity>>> MyIncludeExpression
{
    get { return e => CacheHelper.Get<List<MySecondEntity>>(CacheKeys.MySecondEntityKey).AsQueryable(); }
}

...

dbContext.MyEntity
    .Where(i => id = 1)
    .Include(i => MyIncludeExpression)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Error:

> The expression 'e => System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MySecondEntity]' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Is there any way it can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: With LINQKit's `Invoke`, it can be translatable. `.Include(i => MyIncludeExpression.Invoke(t))`.  Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72099548/10646316) for enabling LINQKit.