# Proper way to compare request with entity

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have issue with implementation Get method into my manager class. How do i need to filter and where i need to write filter method.

In short - i have data class Gym, repository class and method Find in it. I wrote methods in data classes - IsAppreciateToRequest(RequestName) to do smth like this in manager class

```
public IEnumerable<GymDto> GetGyms(GetGymRequest request)
{
    return _gymRepository
           .Find(gym => gym.IsAppreciateToRequest(request))
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(GymDto.FromEntityToDto);
}
```

I think this is shitcode, but also idk how to get rid of this and how to write it proper way(before this i had Get method like 30-50 lines longer in every manager class)

IsAppreciateToRequest method:

```
 public bool IsAppreciateToRequest(GetGymRequest other)
        {
            return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(other.Name) || Name == other.Name)
                   &&  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(other.Location) || Location == other.Location) 
                   && (other.SectionRequest == null || Sections.All(section => section.IsAppreciateToRequest(other.SectionRequest)));
        }
```

Comment: Show `IsAppreciateToRequest` method body. Maybe we can inject it into filter.

Comment: The problem is?

Comment: The problem is about placing code in right place - i think it`s must be not in data class but idk where it must to be(

Comment: `IsAppreciateToRequest` is member of which class?  And are you ready to use third party extensions?

Comment: IsAppreciateToRequest is a member of every data class i using in my app. This method called while i make filter request. Yes, i`m open to using third party extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for injecting Expression Tree into filters. It is needed to configure `DbContextOptions`:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString) // or any other provider
    .WithExpressionExpanding();     // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Your classes should be extended with static function which returns `Expression<Func<>>` and current methods should have `ExpandableAttribute`

For example:

```cs
public class Gym
{
    [Expandable(nameof(IsAppreciateToRequestImpl))]
    public bool IsAppreciateToRequest(GetGymRequest other)
    {
        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(other.Name) || Name == other.Name)
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(other.Location) || Location == other.Location) 
                && (other.SectionRequest == null || Sections.All(section => section.IsAppreciateToRequest(other.SectionRequest)));
    }

    private static Expression<Func<Gym, GetGymRequest, bool>> IsAppreciateToRequestImpl()
    {
        // first parameter is current object
        return (gym, other) => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(other.Name) || gym.Name == other.Name)
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(other.Location) || gym.Location == other.Location) 
                && (other.SectionRequest == null || gym.Sections.All(section => section.IsAppreciateToRequest(other.SectionRequest)));
    }
}

// the same technique as in Gym class
public class Section
{
    [Expandable(nameof(IsAppreciateToRequestImpl))]
    public bool IsAppreciateToRequest(GetSectionRequest other)
    {
        return // unknown;
    }

    private static Expression<Func<Section, GetSectionRequest, bool>> IsAppreciateToRequestImpl()
    {
        // first parameter is current object
        return (section, other) => // unknown;
    }
}
```

Then LINQKit will expand expressions returned by your static methods and will inject conditions into predicate.

The same approach can be used for projecting entity to DTO. Similar my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316), which also shows known alternatives for LINQKit.