# EF Core: How to provide efficient (queryable) access to indirectly related entities from domain?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Suppose we have three entities `A`, `B`, `C` with a many-to-one relationship `A -> B` and a many-to-one relationship `B -> C`.

In our domain source of `A` we then have:

```cs
class A 
{
   public ICollection<B> relatedBs { get; private set; }
}
```

Since the relationship is mapped via `HasOne(...).WithMany(...)` a call to `dbContext.As.SelectMany(a => a.relatedBs)` will be translated to a join on sql level, especially returning an `IQueryable<B>` which I can extend without enforcing client side evaluation.

The situation with `B.relatedCs` is analogous.

Now, the call

```
dbContext.As.SelectMany(a => a.relatedBs.SelectMany(b => b.relatedCs))
```

will be translated into a join of all three tables as expected.

But: if we add the following property to `A`:

```cs
public IEnumerable allRelatedCs => relatedBs.SelectMany(b => b.relatedCs)
```

which is ignored in the db configuration because there is no direct relation, the expression

```
dbContext.As.SelectMany(a => a.allRelatedCs).ToQueryString()
```

throws:

> InvalidOperationException: "The LINQ expression 'ag => ag.Vorgaenge' could not be translated."

The point is, that I need the property `A.allRelatedCs` since it is part of the domain logic, but I also want that the above call correctly resolves to the same `IQueryable` as the two-layer-select-many above which resolves to the same SQL query.

My questions:

- Is this possible?
- Why does it not work this way? As far as I see, I am just writing the same expression in another way, so what goes wrong? I thought it could be because allRelatedCs is an `IEnumerable`, but the resulting expression is in fact an `IQueryable`, only the call to `ToQueryString()` fails (from which I conclude that further LINQ calls force client side evaluation)

Comment: It is possible but with usage of third party libraries, which corrects Expression Tree before translating by EF Core, like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). If you interested will prepare answer.

Comment: How does your class B refers to class A? Do you have something like this: public virtual ClassA A { get; set; } ? And the same to your class C?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It sounds interesting, but is there any reference which states that pure ef is not able to do that?

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues Yes, The many to one relations are configured both ways.

Comment: EF cannot look into method body and predict which query to build. This is common sense. Also I'm good in LINQ translation and I know how EF Core works and which limitations it has.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for such task. For activating you can use `DbContextOptionsBuilder`:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString) // or any other provider
    .WithExpressionExpanding();     // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Decorate property with `ExpandableAttribute`:

```cs
public class A
{
    // other properties

    [Expandable(name(allRelatedCsImpl))]
    public IEnumerable<C> allRelatedCs 
        => relatedBs.SelectMany(b => b.relatedCs);

    // we return Expression which will be embedded into the main query
    private static Expression<Func<A, IEnumerable<C>>> allRelatedCsImpl()
        // a == this
        => a => a.relatedBs.SelectMany(b => b.relatedCs);
}
```

Then your query should be translated sucessfully:

```cs
dbContext.As.SelectMany(a => a.allRelatedCs).ToQueryString();
```

`LINQKit` is not alone and there are other libraries which can do the same thing. Brief overview is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316), it can be simpler to use `DelegateDecompiler`, for example.