# How can I use a projection expression for single (non-collection) entities?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

Using .net-6 and EF Core 6, I want to define reusable projections using expressions so that I can centralize DTO mappings in one place.

Given an entity with relationships:

```
class Property {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public List<Amenity> Amenities {get; set;}
  public Address Address {get; set;}
}

class Amenity {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Value {get; set;}
}

class Address {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Country {get; set;}
  public string City {get; set;}
  public string Street {get; set;}
}
```

And their DTOs:

```
class PropertyDto {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public List<AmenityDto> Amenities {get; set;}
  public AddressDto Address {get; set;}
}

class AmenityDto{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Value {get; set;}
}

class AddressDto{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Country {get; set;}
  public string City {get; set;}
  public string Street {get; set;}
}
```

I can create a reusable projection expression:

```
public class PropertyDto {
  ...
  public static Expression<Func<Property, PropertyDto>> Projection =
    property => new PropertyDto{
      Id = property.Id,
    };
  ...
}
```

That I can use in any query's `Select()` call as the projection expression, which EF will "visit" and translate into SQL to fetch only those columns I need:

```
DbContext.Set<Property>()
  .Select(Property.Projection)
  .ToListAsync();
```

If I want to reuse projections for Amenities I can create a Projection expression for `AmenityDto` and do the following:

```
public static Expression<Func<Property, PropertyDto>> Projection =
    property => new PropertyDto{
      Id = property.Id,
      Amenities = property.Amenities.AsQueryable().Select(Amenity.Dto).ToList(),
    };
```

But if I want to do the same for `Address` I can't use `.Select()` to project it because it's not a collection.

```
public static Expression<Func<Property, PropertyDto>> Projection =
    property => new PropertyDto{
      Id = property.Id,
      Amenities = property.Amenities.AsQueryable().Select(Amenity.Dto).ToList(),
      Address = // how can I use AddressDto.Projection here?
    };
```

The Address field expects an AddressDto. If I use a callback e.g. `AddressDto.Projection(address)` EF will load the whole entity because it can't translate the method to SQL. After a lot of google I have only come across some articles discussing the use of `.AsExpandable()` or `[ReplaceWithExpression]` attribute to instruct EF to replace a method with an expression. As far as I can tell, none of these longer work in EF Core 6.0

Is there any way I can reuse projection expressions when projecting a single entity?

Comment: Check [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316). Maybe it will be more useful for you. Anyway with LINQKit we can also correct your code.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I had run into LINQKit but wasn't aware it was capable of doing this. I'm also surprised none of my Google searches brought up that SO thread. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, and thanks to the comment by @SvyatoslavDanyliv, here is what I did to solve my issue:

1. I installed `LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`
2. I created a method that returns the expression for projecting my domain model to the Dto equivalent:

```
public static Expression<Func<Address, AddressDto>> Projection() =>
   address => new AddressDto
   {
       Id = address .Id,
       Country = address.Country,
       City = address.City,
       Street = address.Street,
   };
```

3. I created the method that will be called from within other projections, and which LinqKit will replace with the projection expression above.

```
[Expandable(nameof(Projection))]
public static AddressDto FromEntity(Address address)
{
    // If you want to use this method outside of projections
    // return Projection().Compile().Invoke(address);
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I decided to `throw new NotImplementedException()` because I will only be calling this method from within projections, but if you wish to reuse this method to create DTOs elsewhere in your codebase you can compile & invoke your projection.

4. I used the replaceable Dto projection method in my parent EF projections:

```
...
.Select(property => new PropertyDto{
   Id = property.Id,
   Address = AddressDto.FromEntity(property.Address),
   ...
})
...
```

The resulting EF SQL properly selects only those columns used by the child Dto.