# Business Object to DTO conversion

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, automapper, dto

I have a list of types of `application`. I want to transform that object to an object of type `ApplicationDTO`. Inside that `Application` business object, there is a list of Applicants of the type `Applicant`. Now my DTO has the same list but I am struggling with how to assign the list members of the business object to the list inside the DTO. I have had multiple such occurrences where it is not known how many items I have on the list.
Here is an example:

```
// List of business objects
List<Application> ApplicationList = await _dbContextDigitVP.Applications.FromSqlRaw("Exec dbo.GetApplication {0}", id).ToListAsync();

//DTO object
ApplicationDTO applicationDTO = new ApplicationDTO
{
    ApplicationNumber = Application.ApplicationNumber,
    Country = Application.Country,
    ApplicationUuid = Application.ApplicationUuid,
    PwEmployeeAdUserName = Application.PwEmployeeAdUserName,
    Category = new ApplicationCategoryDTO
    {
        Category = Application.Category?.Category
    },
    Applicants = new List<ApplicantDTO>()
    {
       // add members of the business object                       
    }

};
```

I could go over it with a for loop but is there a way to do this inside the object definition?

Comment: Try https://automapper.org/

Comment: Putting this out here without judgment or bias. But I think it is worth to know that others have found tools like automapper to be not without problems ([here](https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/pitfalls-of-automapper/), [here](https://ivanazure.wordpress.com/2015/12/02/why-automapping-is-bad-for-you/), [here](https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/)). YMMV, but before you commit long-term or large to tools like automapper you should probably read and judge for yourself.

Comment: I searched for like 10 seconds and the first search results were about why not to use automapper - kinda alarming if you ask me

Comment: `Applicants = Application.Applicants.Select(x => new ApplicantDTO { property initizialization here }).ToList()`

Comment: Check this answer [reusing DTO mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use LINQ to transform objects like without using AutoMapper.

```
List<ApplicationDTO> applicationDTOList = ApplicationList.Select(app => new ApplicationDTO
{
    ApplicationNumber = app.ApplicationNumber,
    Country = app.Country,
    ApplicationUuid = app.ApplicationUuid,
    PwEmployeeAdUserName = app.PwEmployeeAdUserName,
    Category = new ApplicationCategoryDTO
    {
        Category = app.Category?.Category
    },
    Applicants = app.Applicants.Select(a => new ApplicantDTO
    {
        // same logic as the above
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: So if there were multiple Applicants in app.Applicants then it would generate for example 2 objects inside the DTO Applicants?

Comment: `Applicants` is also a list

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AutoMapper`.

Once you have your types you can create a map for the two types using a MapperConfiguration and CreateMap. You only need one MapperConfiguration instance typically per AppDomain and should be instantiated during startup.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Application, 
ApplicationDTO>());
```

The type on the left is the source type, and the type on the right is the destination type. To perform a mapping, call one of the Map overloads:

```
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
// or
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
ApplicationDTO dto = mapper.Map<ApplicationDTO>(Application);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Automapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/) to map data from one object to another.

Create Automapper configurations like this for the configure mapping between the `ApplicationDTO` and `Application`, `ApplicationCategory` and `ApplicationCategoryDTO` and `Applicant` to `ApplicantDTO`

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {

  //Source ==> Desti
  //Application and ApplicationDTO classes
  cfg.CreateMap < Application, ApplicationDTO > ()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Category, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Category))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Applicants, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Applicants));
  //ApplicationCategory and ApplicationCategoryDTO classes
  cfg.CreateMap < ApplicationCategory, ApplicationCategoryDTO > ();
  //Applicant and ApplicantDTO classes
  cfg.CreateMap < Applicant, ApplicantDTO > ();
});
```

In your constructor, you can initialize Mapper like

```
private readonly IMapper _Mapper;

   public TestController(IMapper mapper) {
            _Mapper = mapper;
   }
```

When you doing the casting you can do somthing like this,

```
var applicationDTOList = _Mapper.Map<List<ApplicationDTO>>(ApplicationList);
```