# Expression with multiple parameters and int return type in EF Core Where clause

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am using .NET Core 3.1, [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.9) and [Npgsql 4.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/4.1.9). I would like to reuse the `CompareBuilds` function for comparing 2 `Build` objects in `Where(...)` statements. I would like the function to be translated into SQL.

This is the function that I have currently:

```cs
public List<Ticket> GetTicketsForBuild(Build build)
{
    Expression<Func<Build, Build, int>> CompareBuilds = (first, second) =>
        // complex logic, simplified for the sake of example
        first.Version == second.Version ? 0 : (first.Version < second.Version ? -1 : 1);
    
    return _myDbContext.Ticket
        .Where(x => CompareBuilds(x.BuildIntroducedIn, build) <= 0)
        .Where(x => x.IsPublic ?
            CompareBuilds(x.BuildResolvedIn, build) < 0 :
            CompareBuilds(x.BuildResolvedIn, build) > 0)
        .ToList();
}
```

However, the compiler is giving me the following error in the first `Where` clause:

```
CS0149: Method name expected
```

How can I reuse the same function for comparing 2 `Build` objects inside `Where` clauses? Moreover, this function should return an `int`, like it is demonstrated in the code snippet.

Comment: You're getting this error because Expressions cannot be called like that - if you had declared `CompareBuilds` as just a `Func`, then you could've called it like `CompareBuilds(x.BuildIntroducedIn, build)` in your lambda, but an Expression would first have to be `.Compile()`'d, and that of course would make the comparison resolve client-side.

Comment: And declaring it as just a `Func` would make it resolve client-side too.

Comment: Okay, I understand that compiling the `Expression` prevents its translation to SQL. However, I would like the query to be executed at the database level, not on the client. Is there a way to do what I want without compiling the expression, maybe with wrapping it somehow, using compiled queries, ...?

Comment: The way I do it in my codebase is like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/JIPXcw, but it doesn't allow you to further modify the Where condition like you do with the ternary if or `< 0` or `> 0`.

Comment: Maybe what you want to do is achievable with building your own expression trees (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/expression-trees-building), but I can't help with that.

Comment: Exactly, I have seen a lot of examples like this one. I am using this approach in my codebase as well for predicate clauses. However, I haven't yet found an example of how to use the result of the `Expression<Func<...>>` in `Where` clause (ex. `< 0`). I will take a look at building my own expression tree.

Comment: You need `LINQKit` here. If you interested I can show sample.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes, please, I would really appreciate an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first activate [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). It needs just configuring `DbContextOptions`:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString) // or any other provider
    .WithExpressionExpanding();     // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Then you can reuse this expression:

```cs
public List<Ticket> GetTicketsForBuild(Build build)
{
    Expression<Func<Build, Build, int>> CompareBuilds = (first, second) =>
        // complex logic, simplified for the sake of example
        first.Version == second.Version ? 0 : (first.Version < second.Version ? -1 : 1);
    
    return _myDbContext.Ticket
        .Where(x => CompareBuilds.Invoke(x.BuildIntroducedIn, build) <= 0)
        .Where(x => x.IsPublic ?
            CompareBuilds.Invoke(x.BuildResolvedIn, build) < 0 :
            CompareBuilds.Invoke(x.BuildResolvedIn, build) > 0)
        .ToList();
}
```

But usually such functions are handy in other queries and we can do it more generic way:

```cs
public static class QueryHelper
{
    [Expandable(nameof(CompareBuildsImpl))]
    public static int CompareBuilds(Build first, Build second)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationexception();
    }

    private static Expression<Func<Build, Build, int>> CompareBuildsimpl()
    {
        return (first, second) =>
            // complex logic, simplified for the sake of example
            first.Version == second.Version ? 0 : (first.Version < second.Version ? -1 : 1);
    }
}
```

And reuse in queries:

```cs
public List<Ticket> GetTicketsForBuild(Build build)
{    
    return _myDbContext.Ticket
        .Where(x => QueryHelper.CompareBuilds(x.BuildIntroducedIn, build) <= 0)
        .Where(x => x.IsPublic ?
            QueryHelper.CompareBuilds(x.BuildResolvedIn, build) < 0 :
            QueryHelper.CompareBuilds(x.BuildResolvedIn, build) > 0)
        .ToList();
}
```

There are other libraries which do the same thing and I have collected some of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Just one small remark for all future readers. If you don't want to enable LinqKit globally, you can enable it per-query by using `_myDbContext.Ticket.AsExpandable()`.