# Is there a way to filter within the child properties using include or select in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: database, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am trying to figure out a way of applying a second layer filter on a collection which is a child element in my context object.

I am just going to use the public examples from ms querying data page and adjust accordingly to my needs:

```cs
public async Task<List<BlogDto>> GetByNavigationPropertyAsync(Expression<Func<Model, bool>> filterExpression, Expression<Func<Posts, bool>> advancedFilterExpression)
{
    using (var context = new BloggingContext())
    {
        var blogs = context.Blogs
                           .Where(filterExpression)
                           .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                           .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
                           .ToList();
    }
}
```

What I have been trying to achieve is to filter the data on posts based on `advancedFilterExpression` and convert it into a Dto.

What I have tried is:

1. I have used include and then include using this on where I want to filter:

```cs
.Include(sv => sv.Posts.AsQueryable().Where(advancedFilterExpression))
```

Here I have achieved filtering but the issue is that I have more calls to `.ThenInclude` which returns a lot of data from the database and I don't want unnecessary data.

2. I also have removed the include calls use a `.Select` where I get the desired data but here I did not find a way to apply my `advancedFilterExpression`.

Of what I have seen using a combination of these 2 won't work because

`.Select` will ignore the `.Include` so applying a filtering there will have no affect.

I might as very well not understand Entity Framework Core completely, and to juggle with the options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for such filtering. It needs just configuring `DbContextOptions`:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString) // or any other provider
    .WithExpressionExpanding();     // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Your query, using LINQLit's `Invoke`

```cs
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Where(filterExpression)
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts.Where(p => advancedFilterExpression.Invoke(p)))
    .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
    .ToList();
```

It should work for `Select` also

```cs
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Where(filterExpression)
    .Select(b => new BlogsDto
    {
        Id = b.Id,
        // .. other properties
        Posts = blog.Posts.Where(p => advancedFilterExpression.Invoke(p))
            .Select(p => new PostDto {...})
            .ToList()
        
        Author = new AuthorDto{...}
    })
    .ToList();
```

Projecting to DTO also can be reused [AsDto sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316)