# Use an Expression to fill out object property inside a Select clause

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I have a specific Expression that is dynamically generated that I want to reuse in a Select statement that ultimately will be execute by EF Core as SQL in Postgres. So I am of course limited to creating expressions in a way that can be translated to SQL.

Let's call the EF Core entity in the database `Thing`, it has a property `Id` and I have a method `GeneratePermissionsExpression`that generates an expression of the type `Expression<Func<Thing, bool>>`. This is essentially a kind of permissions check, you pass it a Thing and it gives back true or false.

I'm using this expression in a different place, and now I want to reuse it here to generate a List of `{Id, HasPermission}` objects, each element of the list representing this permissions check for one Thing. I can use my existing expression without issue to just generate a list of bools representing the permissions check, but in this case I also need the corresponding Ids.

What I've done so far only requires some lambda literals and the right types, but now it looks like I have to manipulate and generate Expression trees and that is a lot more complex. I tried a few things, including using Expression.Invoke, but I didn't get anywhere with that. I managed to generate an Expression representing the function "(Id, HasPermission) => new PermissionsIdResult() {Id = Id, HasPermission = HasPermission}", but failed when trying to use that to achieve my goal, and I suspect I was on entirely the wrong path there.

The code that works and only produces a list of bools looks like the following, `ids` in this case is a List of ints, GeneratePermissionsExpression is the method that returns my `Expression<Func<Thing, bool>>`:

```
 var query = context.Things
   .Where(t => ids.Contains(t.Id))
   .Select(GeneratePermissionsExpression());
```

This query is then executed with ToListAsync() by EF Core.

What I now want to do looks more like the following, but obviously that code doesn't work nor compile:

```
var query = context.Things
   .Where(t => ids.Contains(t.Id))
   .Select( new ResultClass{Id = t.Id, HasPermission = GeneratePermissionsExpression());
```

ResultClass is simply a class containing the `{Id, HasPermission}` properties, I wanted to avoid dealing with anonymous classes here. Now what the part where I write

```
HasPermission = GeneratePermissionsExpression()
```

should do is to use the Expression that method returns to fill out the HasPermission property on my ResultClass object. I tried using Invoke here, but then I get InvocationExpressions I can't run with EF Core against the database.

How can I use my `Expression<Func<Thing, bool>>` to fill out the HasPermission property on that object and have all that executed in the database in the end?

Comment: Check this [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Is the only way to do this to use a library? And I don't really get why this should require decompiling as I already have my function as an Expression.

Comment: You can use LINKQKit and it's `Expandable` attribute. Or use LINQKit's `Invoke` extension. Anyway without additional Expression Tree preparation it will not work - it is what these libraries do.