# Use Expression<Func<T, TResult>> as select part in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this property in my model class:

```
[NotMapped]
public static Expression<Func<Product, bool>> ProductColorHasStockExp = (x => x.ProductColors.Any(c => !c.IsDeleted && (c.Stock > c.SellCount + c.WarningPoint)));
```

I can use it in `OrderBy` and it works fine:

```
.ThenByDescending(Product.ProductColorHasStockExp)
.ThenByDescending(Product.FinalPriceExp)
```

But I can't use it in the `Select` part as shown here:

```
.Select(p => new
             {
                 p.Title,
                 p.TitleURL,
                 FinalPrice = Product.FinalPriceExp
                 HasStock = Product.ProductColorHasStockExp,
                 SellCount = Product.SellCountExp,
             }).ToList();
```

Of course I can use something like this:

```
FinalPrice = p.ProductColors == null ||
             !p.ProductColors.Any(c => !c.IsDeleted) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(p.ProductColors.FirstOrDefault(c => !c.IsDeleted).Price - ((float)p.ProductColors.FirstOrDefault(c => !c.IsDeleted).Price * p.ProductColors.FirstOrDefault(c => !c.IsDeleted).Discount / 100)),
```

and this works fine, but I need a way to reuse things so if the formula changes, I just change a part of code.

Ah and it is not .NET Core - it is the "old" ASP.NET MVC

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF doesn't know how to translate a custom method call (which `Product.SellCountExp` basically is) into SQL when it's embedded into another expression (i.e. the entire LINQ query).

The best option to solve this (I think) is to create a DTO class and use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org) to map `SellCount` to `Product.SellCountExp`, etc.

```cs
class ProductDto
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleURL { get; set; }
    public int FinalPrice { get; set; }
    public bool HasStock { get; set; }
    public int SellCount { get; set; }
}
```

Automapper configuration:

```cs
class ProductMappingProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public ImportProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FinalPrice, m => m.MapFrom(Product.FinalPriceExp))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.HasStock, m => m.MapFrom(Product.ProductColorHasStockExp))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SellCount, m => m.MapFrom(Product.SellCountExp));
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;

...

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<ProductMappingProfile>());

var dtos = context.Products
    .ProjectTo<ProductDto>(config).ToList();
```

I assume you're using EF6 (classic). If so, you'll have to replace `Convert.ToInt32` by `(int)`.

There are libraries that are able to convert method calls to expressions, but they usually require some addition to DTO classes or to the LINQ query to make them work. AutoMapper has become a first-class citizen in the .net stack, making it my preferred library.

Comment: ty man that converts works because i uses ToList() then used that .

Comment: but why  Product.ProductColorHasStockExp works as an order by  but not in select part?

Comment: Because then you use it as a parameter in the `OrderBy` method, which expects an expression. It's not a method returning an expression embedded in another expression.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) or similar libraries for such case. Use appropriate version for EF6:

Methods `Invoke` and `AsExpandable` is a key for making it working.

```cs
var result = query.Select(p => new
   {
      p.Title,
      p.TitleURL,
      FinalPrice = Product.FinalPriceExp.Invoke(p),
      HasStock = Product.ProductColorHasStockExp.Invoke(p),
      SellCount = Product.SellCountExp.Invoke(p),
   })
   .AsExpandable()
   .ToList();
```

Library should extract `Expression` from method and inject into query before passing to EF.

Also check this sample for [AsDto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316), probbaly you will find useful `ExpandableAttribute`.

Comment: ty man i want use less library if i want use something else i rather use dapper and change whole project but i gona test this LINQKit